# aws workspace windows 10, 2019 server: does they have ssm agent installed by default

Tags: powershell, amazon-workspaces

I have a created a aws workspace (windows 10, 2019 server freetier), I want to use AWS session manger or SSM to handle some operation on the workspace.

I opened the windows workspace and tried

```
PS D:\Users\sant8test> Get-Service -Name "AmazonSSMAgent"

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  AmazonSSMAgent     Amazon SSM Agent
```

SO i see the Amazon SSM agent is already running

I want to modify its activation-code-code and activation-id, how is it possible

Comment: What did you try so far? Is this about PowerShell or just the Amazon workspace? Do you have any example (in other programming language)? Looks like you are **Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more**...

Comment: The following shows how to config SSM Agent : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html